# How to pass asynchronous values ​from display to method - Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How to pass asynchronous values ​​from display to method - Vue?

The return is an error indicating that the function does not exist.

Where can I be wrong?

Thank you guys

```
methods: {
      teste (value) {
        console.log(value)
      }
},
display: function () {
      this.teste(true)
}
```

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _this2.teste is not a
>   function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you would need to add a display function at the component level? You should not have functions outside of methods object, for a component. Because these are not part of Vue components conception.

```
methods: {
      teste (value) {
         console.log(value)
      },
      display: function () {
         this.teste(true)
      }
}
```